# Bash - Removing white space from indented multiline strings

Tags: bash, printf, echo, indentation

This may be a more general question so sorry in advance. I am creating a script and thought it would be good to use multi-line strings instead of using multiple printf or echo statements. Say I have the following:

```
while :
do
 printf "line 1
 line 2
 line 3"
done
```

The second and third lines would be printed with a space in front because of the indentation in the file.

```
l1
 line 2
 line 3
```

Is there a way to prevent that aside from removing the indentation on the code? Also, is it considered a better practice to just multiple printf/echo statements if you need to output information that spans multiple lines?

Answer (score 5):

Indent with tabs (here whitespace) and use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) (with `<<-`)

```
cat <<- EOF
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3
EOF
```

Comment: **note:** pay attention to the "*Indent with* `tabs`" (spaces will not do). If your editor inserts spaces instead of `tabs`, then you can do away with the indentation and simply use `<<` as the *heredoc* sigil.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-line strings will always look a bit bad, or have some other downsides, I'm afraid. The most legible way to embed them in bash code is probably the here-doc, which shows the string (almost) exactly like it will look when output. As an extra knack, you can use extra punctuation to make the here-doc delimiter to stand out from the string itself too, like so:

```
if true
then
    some commands

    cat <<"____EndOfTextBlock____"
This text here
spans multiple        
lines.
____EndOfTextBlock____

    some other commands
    even more commands
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the indentation within you script (e.g. for better readability) while removing it from the output by using `sed`

```bash
cat << EOT | sed 's/^ *//g'
    line1
    line2
    line3
EOT
```